# Alt Menu Shortcut Keys not working normally in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

Ever since I was given a Windows 8 Dell laptop at work, I've been unable to use the "Alt+underlined letter" shortcuts that I'm used to in order to open menus in windows applications.

The only way to use menus by shortcuts is to change this shortcut into 2 keystrokes.  "Alt" to open the menu, release the key and then a second keystroke to hit the underlined letter corresponding to the menu that I wish to use.

However, if I try to do it as the Alt+letter (combined, or without releasing the Alt) it ignores the letter.

I originally assumed that this was another annoying Windows 8 UI change until I used someone else's Windows 8 laptop and found that Alt+letter opened menus fine on her PC.  Obviously, this isn't universal on Windows 8.

I've tried many Google searches.  I've checked out keyboard settings and usability settings, but have come up dry.  I'm stumped!

This is clashing with decades of muscle memory...

Comment: What keyboards do you have installed?  What languages do you have installed?

Comment: I'm higly dubious as this having anything to do with the actual keyboard hardware.  I'm using a plain Dell L100 external keyboard currently, but this has occurred with about 4 or 5 other random keyboards I've used at different times, and on the built-in keyboard on the Dell Inspiron i17R-1316sLV.  Only "English (United States)" is installed.

Comment: Well there is something unique about your installation.  What about my other half my question

Comment: I don't follow. What other half?  I answered about keyboards and language.

Comment: Are there particular applications that are not responding to Alt+key shortcuts?   I have this same issue /w Windows 8 and Office 2013.   I have to press ALT then a letter (but cant press both at the same time) to bring up the menus I am so accustomed to opening via pressing ALT+key at the same time.   It just suddenly started to happen one day and I don't have any idea why :(

Comment: Could it be that your "Sticky keys" are on (In accessibility options)? I didn't think it would prevent you from pressing Alt+Letter at the same time (at least in Windows 7) but it gives you the ability to first press Alt, release it and then press the Letter.

Comment: Richie086 - It isn't particular applications.  It's all applications.
Rik -  Sticky Keys are off.

Comment: I don't know if it helps or not, but the same behavior exists even in my Windows XP that I'm running under VMWare under the Windows 8 host.

Comment: Someone [here](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2066197) had the same problem. Could you try selecting another country/language for your keyboard in Windows 8 to see if it solves it?

Comment: Changing my keyboard country/language did not help.

Comment: You could try 2 more things. Add another user and try it under that account. You could also start in ["Safe mode"](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/ss/windows-8-safe-mode.htm) and see if it happens, in say Notepad.